# Batch file save a text as date and time in a new folder

Tags: date, batch-file, time, save

I have a batch file that opens a PDF and selects all of the text, copies it then pastes it into a new blank text document. The PDF and the text document are in the same folder as the batch file as I need to be able to give it to others. I need to save the text document to a new folder with the name of the current date and time to prevent duplicate names.

```
[code]
@echo off
start PP15ShirazTimesheet.pdf
timeout 5 > NUL
start select.vbs
start copy.vbs
timeout 5 > NUL
type NUL > EmptyFile.txt
start EmptyFile.txt
start paste.vbs
[/code]
```

this is what I have so far and the vbs files are just sendkeys. So my question is, how do I save the text file in a new folder with date and time as the name? I'm looking for simple solutions nothing over the moon. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next code snippet:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
for /F %%g in ('
  wmic OS get LocalDateTime /value^|findstr "="
  ') do for /F %%G in ("%%g") do set "_%%G"
echo %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%
MKDIR %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%\
type NUL > %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%\EmptyFile.txt
start %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%\EmptyFile.txt
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%g` to retrieve the `LocalDateTime` value;
- `%%G` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` instead of common `0x0D0A`).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

**Edit**

> The code works great except that it creates a new folder instead of
>   renaming the file into and an existing folder.

```
echo %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%
rem MKDIR %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%\
type NUL > %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
start %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
```

or

```
type NUL > EmptyFile.txt
start EmptyFile.txt
start "" /W paste.vbs
RENAME EmptyFile.txt %_LocalDateTime:~0,14%.txt
```

Comment: you can omit the second `for` here, as you snip the line ending together with the unwanted digits with `:~0,14`. (I would `set _LocalDateTime=%_LocalTimeDate:~0,14%`)

Comment: The code works great except that it creates a new folder instead of renaming the file into and an existing folder. I probably put it in wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: @EduardAnghelescu Exactly as proposed: _I need to save the text document to a new folder with the name of the current date and time_.

Comment: Oops my bad! My English isn't my greatest subject but I did get it to work the way I need it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Stephan yes, it's the case.  However, I strive to give a transcendent solution if possible. People ask here to learn, I hope:)

Comment: Yes it was lots of help! I'm still trying to change the directory because I change EmptyFile to the dateTime line which now names it correctly just in the current folder.